# Can't access data inside an object - rookie Javascript question

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, get

This is a rookie question about accessing an array inside an object and converting it to JSON.

Error I am getting when running the GET method below:

> Cannot read property 'VehicleList' of undefined

How to fix this?

```
let get = https.get(
    {
    hostname: 'xyz.com',
    path: path_get_all_vehicles //this variable is known and passed into path
    },
    (getRes) => {
      console.log(`executing getRes...`);
      var reply = "";
      getRes.on("data", (chunk) => {
        (reply += chunk);
        }
      );
      getRes.on("end", () => {
        gotCars(JSON.parse.stringify(reply.Response.VehicleList)); //ERROR
        }
      );
    }
  );
```

Data format is shown below and the idea is to access the VehicleList array, convert it to JSON and then pass it, after parsing, to function **gotCars**

```
{
  "ResponseStatus": 1,
  "Response": {
    "VehicleList": [
      {
        "ID": AAA,
        "BrandID": 89,
        "ModelID": 980,
        "VersionID": 11289
      },
      {
        "ID": BBB,
        "BrandID": 89,
        "ModelID": 980,
        "VersionID": 8338
      },
    ],
    "VehicleCount": 17866
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(reply)` just before calling `gotCars()`?

Comment: It looks like the way that you are building `reply` is by appending chunks to a string.  So my best guess would be that by the time your `end` handler executes that `reply` is already a stringified JSON object.  I'd recommend trying first setting `reply` equal to `JSON.parse(reply)` in your handler and _then_ try `gotCars(JSON.parse.stringify(reply.Response.VehicleList))`.

Comment: What is `JSON.parse.stringify()`? `JSON.parse()` converts JSON to an object/array, and `JSON.stringify()` converts an object/array to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `JSON.parse.stringify(reply.Response.VehicleList)` is invalid for a couple reasons:

- The global `JSON.parse` does not have a property named `stringify` (`undefined`)
- `undefined` cannot be called
- The global `String.prototype` (`reply` is a string) does not have a property named `Response` (`undefined`)
- `undefined` cannot be indexed

I assume you are trying to parse `reply` as JSON and then get the `VehicleList` array from the result, try this code:

```js
let get = https.get(
  {
    hostname: "xyz.com",
    path: path_get_all_vehicles // this variable is known and passed into path
  },
  (getRes) => {
    console.log(`executing getRes...`);
    var reply = "";
    getRes.on("data", (chunk) => {
      reply += chunk;
    });
    getRes.on("end", () => {
      gotCars(JSON.parse(reply).Response.VehicleList);
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to parse `reply`, that will create the object. Then you can access its properties.

```
      getRes.on("end", () => {
        const obj = JSON.parse(reply);
        gotCars(obj.Response.VehicleList);
      });
```